# Changing processor

Tags: 64-bit, cpu

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 - 32 bits.
On next Tuesday I will change my processor to 64 bits.
Question: What will happen with my pictures stored in a Pendrive?
Will I be able to watch them with the new processor?
On the other hand, I have in my actual hard disk several familiar videos.
What will happen with them with the new processor?
And everything I have now in my Home?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing should happen to them it in theory display better...

Comment: But please, make a backup of all your data before you do the changes!

Comment: Depending on how much RAM you have, you may also wish to upgrade Ubuntu to the 64-bit version.

Comment: The reason I will change is my RAM. I have only 2 Gib of RAM.

Comment: Charles Green, I am saving some arhives on a pendrive, such as photos, videos, documents... Which would be my data, /home? Thanks.

Comment: I made backup of my /home, photos, videos, and stored in Windows partition but as I will change Windows too to 64 bits, this Backup will desappear? If so, where else can I make Backup, on a Pendrive? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Data is stored in 8-bit chunks called bytes. CPU's on the PC platform started out at 16-bit (2 bytes processed at a time). In the 1980's the 32-bit CPU appeared (4 bytes processed at a time). Around 2003 64-bit CPU's (8 bytes processed at a time) began to appear on the PC platform.

To summarize your Data is always stored in 8-bit chunks and it doesn't matter how many bits your CPU can process in a single instruction. Programs must be compiled to match the specific number of bits in the CPU so those will have to change but your Image files will not have to be modified.

Comment: Although since the OP is running a 32-bit OS, he will gain no benefit from using a 64-bit CPU

Comment: @AndroidDev your comment really belongs under OP question and not my answer. The OP can't pull out a 32-bit CPU and put a 64-bit one into the socket. The OP has to buy a whole new 64-bit machine. On that new machine OP would likely install 64-bit software and copy his image files over.

Comment: *"The OP can't pull out a 32-bit CPU and put a 64-bit one into the socket."* - Errrmm... I've done that before :)

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes there are cases (with laptops especially) where a 64 bit bus motherboard with full 64 bit support chips was dumbed down with a 32 bit CPU. In those cases, as long as the BIOS supports it, a 64 bit CPU that is pin compatible can be installed in place of the 32 bit CPU. I think it's rare but on rereading the OP you might have divined the operation correctly :) PS before everyone in the world gets their hopes up this is primarily when socket has the pins and not the CPU and when CPU is soldered into motherboard all bets are off.